# Show do you set unique attributes for resources in Puppet when utilizing arrays

Tags: puppet

In Puppet you can use arrays when declaring resources as so:

```
file { ["/tmp/file1", "/tmp/file2"]:
   ensure => file,
}
```

However, as far as I know both file1 and file2 must have the same attributes, content, etc...  Is there a way to have file1 and file2 have differing attributes?  Something like:

```
myContent = { "/tmp/file1" => "foo", "/tmp/file2" => "bar" }
file { ["/tmp/file1", "/tmp/file2"]:
   ensure => file,
   content => myContent[name],
}
```

So file1 contains foo and file2 contains bar?  As far as I know this comes down to being able to tell if the resource is for file1 or file2, at which point options like hashes or inline templates should become viable, but I'm not sure if this is possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

You could use Hiera with create_resources:

manifest: `create_resources('file', hiera('filez'))`

Hierafile:

```
---
filez:
  /tmp/file1:
    content: foo
  /tmp/file2:
    content: bar
```